# postgresql: selecting on the basis of the latest pivot row

Tags: postgresql

Given a simple schema:

```
users
-----
- id<int>
- name<string>

organisations
-------------
- id<int>
- name<string>

organisations_users
-------------------
- id<int>
- userId<int>
- organisationId<int>
- joinedAt<date>
```

The N:N relation between users and organisations is tracking the organisational history of an individual user.

How do I get all the users who are *currently* at organisation X? This is basically the same as sorting the pivot table by `joinedAt`, then only getting the latest `organisationId` for each user, and then joining with the users who match. I've thought of various ways of collecting all the information I need but the only way I can think of doing this is `filter`ing in the application code rather than in the SQL query itself (but I'm sure there's a way of doing it).

### sample data

```
insert into users (id, name) values
    (1, 'Test User One'),
    (2, 'Test User Two'),
    (3, 'Test User Three');

insert into organisations (id, name) values
    (1, 'Test Org One'),
    (2, 'Test Org Two'),
    (3, 'Test Org Three');

insert into organisations_users ("userId", "organisationId", "joinedAt") values
    (1, 1, '2015-01-01'),
    (1, 2, '2016-01-01'),
    (2, 2, '2015-01-01'),
    (2, 3, '2016-01-01'),
    (3, 3, '2015-01-01'),
    (3, 2, '2016-01-01');
```

At this point, users [1, 3] are in organisation 2 and user 2 is in organisation 3. No-one is in organisation 1.

### expected result

if I were to try to get everyone in organisation 2 I would obtain users 1 and 3 (with their `joinedAt` dates):

```
id | name            | organisationId | joinedAt
--------------------------------------------------
1  | Test User One   | 2              | 2016-01-01
3  | Test User Three | 2              | 2016-01-01
```

I would *not* get user 2, because although this user was in organisation 2 initially, the user joined organisation 3 subsequently.

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Since there is a `JoinedAt` column in the `organisations_users` table, but not a `QuittedAt` column, *every* user who was *ever* present in organisation `X` will still be present.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: will do now

Comment: @wildplasser: no, new organisations supersede previous ones

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: edited with sample data and expected result.

Comment: postgresql, yes you're right I'll correct (but the point of this is still valid)

Comment: (this was supposed to just be illustrative, the actual system is a lot more complex than this so I've boiled the problem down to a simple example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select u.id, u.name, ou.organisationId, ou.joinedat
from users u
  join (
     select userid, organisationid, joinedat, 
            max(joinedat) over (partition by userid) as last_join 
     from organisations_users
  ) ou on u.id = ou.userid and ou.joinedat = ou.last_join
where ou.organisationid = 2;
```

This assumes that a single user can't be in two organisations at the same time. So the most recent joinedat value identifies the user's current organisation.

If a user can join multiple organisations at the same time, you would need to change `max(joinedat) over (partition by userid)` to `max(joinedat) over (partition by userid, organisationid)`

---

Another option is to use `distinct on ()` instead of a window function. Usually the `distinct on ()` solution performs better:

```
select u.id, u.name, ou.organisationId, ou.joinedat
from users u
  join (
     select distinct on (userid) userid, organisationid, joinedat 
     from organisations_users
     order by userid, joinedat desc
  ) ou on u.id = ou.userid 
where ou.organisationid = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative, avoiding window functions and max()

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
        , ou.organisationId
        , ou.joinedAt
FROM users u
JOIN organisations_users ou
        ON u.id = ou.userId
        AND ou.joinedAt <= now()
        AND NOT EXISTS ( -- suppress all but the latest
                SELECT * FROM organisations_users nx
                WHERE nx.userId = ou.userId
                AND nx.organisationId <> ou.organisationId
                AND nx.joinedAt <= now()
                AND nx.joinedAt > ou.joinedAt
                )
WHERE ou.organisationId = 2
        ;
```